# In SpringMVC, is there anyway to select a controller method using a form element value?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC, is there anyway to select a controller method using a form element value? For example, let's say we have two buttons both with name "action" in a form. Is there anyway to execute different controller methods based on the button which was clicked by the user without using any javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using `@RequestMapping(params="...")`.  See [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-advanced).

> You can narrow path mappings through parameter conditions: a sequence of "myParam=myValue" style expressions, with a request only mapped if each such parameter is found to have the given value. For example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/owners/{ownerId}")
public class RelativePathUriTemplateController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/pets/{petId}", params="myParam=myValue")
  public void findPet(@PathVariable String ownerId, @PathVariable String petId, Model model {    
    // implementation omitted
  }
}
```